# My one value is reflecting on another application in MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

When I open two applications in different browsers or in the same browser, the value which I added in one application is visible to the other application.

I have made a session helper but i am still in problem.

```
public class SessionHelper
{
    #region Strongly typed variable
    public static CreateAccountModel tmpmodel = null;
    public static string errMsg = string.Empty;
    public static List<PointOfSalesModel> CurrPosModelArr = null;
    public static List<PointOfSaleUsersModel> currAddedClerks = null;
    public static List<AuthorizedIPsModel> currAddedIPs = null;
    public static bool isPosDataLodedFirstTime = false;
    public static string isEditGridClickedVal = "No";
    public static int AccountId = -1;
    #endregion

    public SessionHelper Current
    {
        get
        {
            SessionHelper currentSession = HttpContext.Current.Session["_session"] as SessionHelper;
            if (currentSession == null)
            {
                currentSession = new SessionHelper();
                HttpContext.Current.Session["_session"] = currentSession;
            }
            return currentSession;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Static fields/properties are shared across all your requests made from browsers. So even though you save it to the session, but each `SessionHelper` will have same static fields referenced. Use instance fields instead.